# How to modify cupsd.conf on 50+ machines

Tags: applescript, printing, cups

I need to modify the `cupsd.conf` file (removal of `PAUSE-PRINTER`/`RESUME-PRINTER`) on 50+ machines to allow non-admin accounts to resume the print queue.

Is there a way I can script this (through AppleScript or shell scripts) so a local admin could run this on each machine?

Comment: There are two very distinct questions here - one is how to push an AppleScript via ARD and the second is how to have AppleScript modify a file with root privileges.   Can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/350528/edit) your question so that you're only asking one.  Be sure to search Ask Different as there are many solutions to both already.

Comment: Hi I have edited my question as I was not really asking about how to push via ARD more about assistance with writing a single script to perform the tasks. Thanks for the Heads-up though.

Comment: My first though is that this modification might be better with a Bash script instead.   You could make a backup of the original then insert the lines you need using `awk`

Comment: Heavily edited to broaden the range for scripting solutions. It still assumes that you will log into each machine to run the script locally (please correct if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying the cupsd.conf I found another route that works by adding every user to the _lpoperator group to allow everyone to pause/resume the print queue:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -t group -a everyone _lpoperator
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 4):

## `cupsenable` - stop/start printers and classes

You should not need to use `sudo` to resume print queues. The CUPS command [`cupsenable`](https://www.cups.org/doc/man-cupsenable.html) can be run by a standard user.